# Python ColumnTransformer SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm receiving a `SettingWithCopyWarning` when applying transformations to a DataFrame using a scikit-learn `ColumnTransformer`, and I'm not sure why that is.

This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("always")

def filling_nan(frame):
    """Fills columns that have null values with zeros."""
    frame.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return frame

def as_is(frame):
    """Returns the DataFrame as it is."""
    return frame

np.random.seed(1337)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df = df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if x<0.15 else x) # Set a few numbers in the dataframe to NaN.

print(df)
```

This is what the original DataFrame looks like...

```
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.262025  0.158684  0.278127  0.459317  0.321001
1  0.518393  0.261943  0.976085  0.732815       NaN
2  0.386275  0.628501       NaN  0.983549  0.443225
3  0.789558  0.794119  0.361262  0.416104  0.584258
4  0.760172  0.187808  0.288167  0.670219  0.499648
```

Then I create the steps in the ColumnTransformer and **I specify the index of the column** rather than the column name.

```
step_filling_nans = ('filling_nans', FunctionTransformer(filling_nan, validate=False), [2, 4])
step_as_is = ('as_is', FunctionTransformer(as_is, validate=False), [0, 1, 3])
```

Then I create the ColumnTransformer...

```
trans = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        step_filling_nans
        , step_as_is # I could pass 'passthrough' to the remainder keyword instead of doing this step.
    ], remainder='drop')
```

Finally, I print the result of the applying the ColumnTransformer to my DataFrame.

```
print(trans.fit_transform(df))
```

This is the output of the transformations. The ColumnTransformer returns a numpy array as expected (with columns 'C' and 'E' first and second respectively), but I don't understand why I'm receiving the **SettingWithCopy** warning.

```
[[0.27812652 0.32100054 0.26202468 0.15868397 0.45931689]
 [0.97608528 0.         0.51839282 0.26194293 0.73281455]
 [0.         0.44322487 0.38627507 0.62850118 0.98354861]
 [0.36126157 0.58425813 0.78955834 0.79411858 0.41610394]
 [0.28816715 0.49964826 0.76017177 0.18780841 0.67021886]]

/bigdisk0/users/belladam/.conda/envs/day_zero_retention/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3787: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  downcast=downcast, **kwargs)
```

I have managed to fix it by changing the filling_nan() function slightly, but I don't understand why that fixes it.

```
def filling_nan(frame):
    """Fills columns that have null values with zeros."""
    frame = frame.fillna(0)
    return frame
```

I've been unable to reproduce the result outside of using a ColumnTransformer so was wondering if it was something to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `ColumnTransformer` behaves this way because it is capable of running in parallel different transformations related to different columns. You can take a look at the [sklearn code itself here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e5698bde9/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py#L38), at line 448. If you want to use parallelization then it is not really safe to work on the same object (same memory location).

By avoiding using `inplace`, you are actually working on copy of the original object, and this settles the problem:

```
def filling_nan(frame):
    """Fills columns that have null values with zeros."""
    frame = frame.fillna(0)
    return frame

def filling_nan_inplace(frame):
    """Fills columns that have null values with zeros."""
    frame.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return frame

print(id(df))
print(id(filling_nan_inplace(df)))
print(id(filling_nan(df)))
```

output:

```
2088604584760
2088604584760
2088604583304
```